# How to set custom RGB color for chart series in Excel 2003?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, colors

According to Internet, Excel 2003 has inherent limitation of allowing only 56 colors in a workbook. Each color used must be present in a color palette.

I need a custom RGB color for my chart (e.g. 10 series, 10 colors which form gradient from red to grey). When I try to set them from macros, Excel convert requested color to nearest one in its palette. Modifying palette is not feasable, since there are many custom colors that I need, more than 56.

Now comes tricky part - if I create a workbook in Excel 2007 with custom series colors, and import/open it in Excel 2003, then colors are preserved(!) and not appended to standard palette. Which leads me to believe, that this Excel 2003 limitation could be overcome somehow in Excel 2003 itself. But how?

How do I set chart serie color to be custom RGB value, using macros?

P.S. I'm actually controlling Excel from Delphi COM object, but the macros solution should be easy to reuse/adapt.

Comment: I doubt this can be done in Excel 2003. Why not use Excel 2007 instead?

Comment: @LPChip this is not my decision, sadly.

Comment: Is the data live and changing, or one-time?